# Узнать номер записи по id (SQLite) Android

Tags: sqlite, java, android, база-данных

Привет!
Осваиваю SQLite, столкнулся с проблемой.

Мне нужно получить номер записи, по id записи...

Допустим в таблице "mytable" 3 записи:

> 1 запись: "id = 4";
> 2 запись: "id = 5";
> 3 запись: "id = 6";

Как я могу найти номер записи с id = 5, например? Можете привести пример с кодом, а то ничего не получается!

Comment: @Oneills, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: пробегать - это плохо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[[@Oneills](/users/19093/oneills)](/users/19093/oneills) в теории реляционных БД к коим относится SQLite нет понятия *номер записи*, то есть нет понятия 1-я запись, 2-я запись, последняя и проч. Я знаю, сначала это кажется диким, но потом когда врубишься все будет простым и логичным.

Вместо категории *номер записи* используются 2 категории:

1. Идентификатор записи - то есть уникальный идентификатор данной конкретной записи. И то это работает не всегда. В некоторых БД даже это отсутствует, ну и тем более когда результатом запроса является сложносоставная запись из нескольких таблиц - где здесь идентификатор?
2. Порядковый номер вывода результатов запроса - то есть порядок сортировки (`order by`)

Здесь важно понимать, что с точки зрения реляционной БД результат запроса ничем не отличается от таблицы. Запрос и таблица - равноценны в реляционной модели данных.

Как только вы поймете эту парадигму - у вас не будут более возникать вопросы связанные с номером записи. В самом деле - вывод равноценный вашему можно получить как минимум 2-мя разными способами:

```
select * from mytable order by id asc
```

или

```
select * from mytable order by id desc
```

И где здесь номер записи?

Как правило, если вам нужен т.н. *номер записи* - значит у вас большие проблемы с пониманием задачи или вы собираетесь создать себе большие проблемы - пытаясь опереться на внутренний порядковый номер записи в файле таблицы, который не может быть гарантирован системой. На одном компе это будет так, а на другом может стать по другому.

**Update**

Собственно если требуется просто перенумеровать строки вывода, то можно применить следующий запрос:

```
select  
   (select count(*) from mytable b where a.id >= b.id) as row_num, 
   id 
   from mytable a order by id asc
```

Comment: >>Как правило, если вам нужен т.н. номер записи - значит у вас большие проблемы с пониманием задачи 
на 100% согласен

Comment: я думаю человек имел ввиду >>"Порядковый номер вывода результатов запроса - то есть порядок сортировки (order by)"

Comment: @Andreich см. апдейт

Answer (score 3):

```
Cursor c = null;
c = db.rawQuery("select ROWID from mytable where id=5", null );
Log.d("mylogs", " recordid = " + c.getInt(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Короче, способ проще (Ну как по мне :)) описан в моем вопросе.
[SQLite Database метод update() выбрать первый элемент БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557242/sqlite-database-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-update-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%91%d0%94)
Вот примерный код. Получаем Курсором все записи
`Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query("ИМЯ ВАШЕЙ ТАБЛИЦЫ", null, null, null, null, null, null);`
Переходим к первой `cursor.moveToFirst()`
Читаем)
`i=0;
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        i++;
        ids[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._ID))+"";
}`
На выходе получаем массив `ids` со всеми id элементов под номерами от 1 до кол-ва записей. Чтобы найти номер по `id` просто ищете по элементам массива нужный id. Все просто)

Comment: Дело в том, что это неправильно с точки зрения использования баз данных. Смотрите принятый ответ - если вам это надо, значит вы что то делаете не так и в дальнейшем это станет проблемой

Comment: Хорошо, возможно это правда правильнее