# SQLite Database метод update() выбрать первый элемент БД

Tags: android, sqlite

Работаю в Android Studio. Для моего проекта мне нужно с помощью метода `update()` выбрать первый элемент моей базы данных (pts). Как это сделать не пойму. Пробовал через это:

```
mSqLiteDatabase.update( "pts",
                    values,
                    DatabaseHelper._ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { Integer.toString(0) } );
```

Так не работает. Наверно из-за того, что совсем не обязательно первый элемент с `_id=0`. Но как выбрать именно **первый** элемент?

Comment: Обновление строки с ID = 0 должно выглядеть как то так:  `mSqLiteDatabase.update( "pts", values, DatabaseHelper._ID + " = ?", new String[] { 0 } );`

Comment: Попытался. То же самое. Возможно моя ошибка в неправильном получении данных из базы, т.к. при изменении всех ячеек в колонне работает.. 
P.s. 
`mSqLiteDatabase.update( "pts", values, DatabaseHelper._ID + " = ?", new String[] { Integer.toString(0) } );`

Comment: Вообще да, ID = 0 не обязательно будет первой записью в выборке, лучше получать непосредственно по ID/ Кстати, если текст выводит, то какой?

Comment: А как это делается?) При последних двух параметрах null
`mSqLiteDatabase.update( "pts",
                        values,
                        null,
                        null`);
Выводит именно то, что я записал в values, но если записать `_id = 0`, или что-то такое, то почему то показывает другую ячейку БД

Comment: [Здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535778/177345) есть пример запроса с выборкой по определенному ID. Вы пишите, что текст выводится, но не тот, а какой именно?

Comment: У меня изначально был неправильный код и теперь я его переделываю. Он у меня, когда надо было изменить значение в ячейке, добавлял новую строку в бд. Короче у меня есть много строк, последняя из которых - Начало 1 2 3 4 5 Конец. Ее мне почему-то выводит.

Comment: То есть вместо первой записи, какой бы ID у нее ни был (метод `moveToFirst()`) вы получаете последнюю?

Comment: Возможно, я что то не так понял, но думаю, что да. Просто в Android Studio нельзя же посмотреть БД? Раньше в моем коде вместо `moveToFirst()` был `moveToLast()`, а вместо `update()` был `insert()`. Я кажется понял, я неправильно получаю данные.

Comment: Чтобы посмотреть БД к Android Studio можно [подключить плагин SQLiteManager](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428785/177345) (в этом же вопросе есть и другие способы прочитать БД). Если вы используете Android Studio версии 2.0 или новее, то стоит [отключить функцию Instant Run](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/553756/177345), так как она не всегда обновляет код при перезапуске.

Comment: Я понял, что у меня не так, и что нужно исправить. Мой `update()` берет не первую запись. Как взять первую? Если у нее не обязательно `_id=0`. В интернете не нашел(( По идее можно создать отдельную колонку для какого-нб числа, но может это велосипед?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Устройство БД таково, что она не имеет привязки к порядковым номерам строк, как например массив, и обычным способом получить доступ на запись именно в первую строку в таблице нельзя. Такова архитектура БД и это может показаться проблемой, но на самом деле это не так, так как с данными БД работают несколько по иному принципу.

Идентификатор, хотя и является автоинкрементируемым значением, но не может служить порядковым индексом, так как при удалении записей из таблицы они просто уничтожаются и идентификаторы следующих за удаленной записью строк не изменяются. То есть при удалении третьей записи идентификаторы будут иметь следующий порядок: 0, 1, 3, 4 .. . При добавлении записи присваивается следующий по по порядку идентификатор.
Не решит эту проблему и отдельная колонка, так как при удалении с ней произойдет тоже, что и с ID, а переписывать все значения этой колонки при каждом удалении крайне нерационально.

Что же делать. А решение простое - чтобы обновить запись в таблице, ее сначала надо было прочитать, соответственно будет получен идентификатор этой записи, его нужно сохранить и при обновлении записи нужно просто указать этот же идентификатор.

Если требуется получить доступ непременно к первой записи (хотя при правильной работе с БД мне сложно придумать, зачем это может понадобиться и способ страдает недостатками), то можно использовать костыль, который заключается в следующем:

1. Сделать выборку в курсор по всей таблице
2. Установить курсор на первую позицию
3. Прочитать ID этой записи
4. Использовать полученный ID для обновления первой записи.

Стоит заметить, что работа с БД довольно сложная дисциплина, которую выделили в отдельную науку - СУБД и с наскоку тут можно только испортить все. Для того, чтобы не испытывать проблем с этой наукой и работой с данными, хранящимися в БД, эту науку следует изучить.
В качестве старта могу предложить замечательную книгу, которая очень легко и интересно читается и дает полное начальное представление о дисциплине СУБД. Прочитав ее, вы откроете для себя много интересного и не совсем очевидного при работе с данными в БД. Книга называется: *Бейли Л. - Изучаем SQL (Бестселлеры O'Reilly) - 2012г.* - найти ее можно и в свободном доступе. Книга о чистом SQL и организации работы с БД и создании ее структуры, но применение изложенных знаний к конкретной БД, вроде SQLite не составит никаких проблем.

Comment: Попытался так сделать, выдает, что `_ID` = null
`cursor.moveToFirst();
        Toast.makeText(findViewById(R.id.chart).getContext(), ""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._ID)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: Что происходит? Попытался вывести все id чезез запятую, вывело только один. С другим полем так же. У меня получается только одно поле? Но почему `_id = null`?
P.s. Спасибо за книжки, почитаю

Comment: Иии.. Да! Я справился! Спасибо вам!

Comment: В чем проблема то была?

Comment: Проблема - у меня не правильно был записан `DATABASE_CREATE_SCRIPT` в `DatabaseHelper`. Получалось, что `_id` являлся типом `String`. Я переписал БД правильно и все заработало по вашему алгоритму.

Answer (score 0):

Я реализовал в своем коде так, при создании новой строки в БД в лог выводится ID только что созданной строки, надеюсь это кому нибудь поможет

```
SQLiteDatabase database;
//Вставка записи в БД
public long add(String name, long remindDate, String icon, String background, String imagesPath) {
    try {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        // установка даты создания
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        long createDate = date.getTimeInMillis();
        contentValues.put(ConstantsDB.KEY_NAME, name); //текст заметки
        contentValues.put(ConstantsDB.KEY_CREATE_DATE, createDate); // дата создания
        contentValues.put(ConstantsDB.KEY_REMIND_DATE, remindDate); // время и дата напоминания
        contentValues.put(ConstantsDB.KEY_ICON, icon); // иконка
        contentValues.put(ConstantsDB.KEY_BACKGROUND, background); //заливка
        contentValues.put(ConstantsDB.KEY_NOTE_IMAGES_PATH, imagesPath); // путь к файлу
        long rowID = database.insert(ConstantsDB.DB_TABLE_NAME, ConstantsDB.KEY_ID, contentValues);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--------Адаптер add---------Test ROW ID  = " + rowID);
        return rowID;


    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```